# Why sizeof() return different values when input is (char) and 'A'

Tags: c, character, sizeof

I am working on `sizeof()`

when I entered argument as char data type

```
J=sizeof(char);
```

It gives output as 1.

But when I entered argument like this

```
J=sizeof('A');
```

I am getting output as 4.

Since it's argument is of `char` data type it should return 1 as output why it is returning 4/2 (Depending upon 32bit/64bit device).

Comment: `sizeof 'A'` will always return 1 in C++. please don't tag random languages in your questions.

Comment: You tagged this question as both C and C++, but which are you actually using? This is one case where it makes a difference!

Comment: `c` or `c++`? They are different languages with different rules and most probably you use only one of them at a time.

Comment: Simply check the C Standard or, I hope, any half-decent tutorial that includes a description of literals, and you will understand.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for suggestions,new to this place will take care from next time :)

Comment: @axiac I am using c.

Answer (score 6):

In C, `'A'` is **not** a constant of type `char`, it is an `int` type. (In C++ it is a `char`.)

C is a model of consistency in this respect; cf. C++ where `'a' + 'b'` is an `int` type as is a multicharacter constant like `'ab'`.

Comment: [Relevant cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant).

Answer (score 5):

It seems you mean C.

In C character literals (called in C character constants) have type `int`. So `sizeof( 'A' )` is equivalent to `sizeof( int )` and yields usually  `4`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The
>   value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined. If an integer character constant contains a
>   single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
>   when an object with type char whose value is that of the single
>   character or escape sequence is converted to type int.

While `sizeof( char )` is alwasy equal to 1.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   1....

Comment: @chux Initially the question was marked with C++ tag where the term character literal is used.

Comment: Yes, such C/C++ questions are made more complex than needed.